# What aspect of a flowfile can I use to differentiate how it was obtained?

Tags: apache-nifi

The never ending scope creep of flowfile sources.

With a single INPUT that obtains flowfiles, is there a way that I can determine how the flowfile was obtained?

For example, the INPUT of flowfile(s) may be obtaining them via the following ways and I'm looking into how to tell its source.

- Generate Flow file processor
- GetFile a single file
- GetFile a single compressed file
- GetFile all files within a directory
- GetFile a flowfile sent via https call

The reason why I need to differentiate is because if the flowfile is a compressed file or a folder of files then I need to route the flow to some logic that does some file management on the server then send the call on to Solr. If the flowfile is based on anything else then direct to only Solr.

I am not seeing anything jumping out at me with the attributes to help differentiate these flowfiles.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NiFi Data Provenance](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#data_provenance) and filter on `CREATE`, `FETCH` and `RECEIVE` events, the results show FlowFiles created by GenerateFlowFile as well as those received from an external system.

If you need to route within the flow you should be able to look at things like the `filename` attribute to determine whether the files are of certain types based on extension and such. You can also add `UpdateAttribute` after each source processor to set an attribute indicating where it came from and perhaps what type it is.